# Is there a way to update my listview page as I navigate back to it?

Tags: android, listview, flutter, dart, navigation

My app has three pages, a homepage, a listview page, and a settings page. I navigate from the homepage to the listview page and on clicking the Floating Action Button in the listview page, I create a new profile and get to the settings page for that profile. Once I have chosen my settings, I want them displayed in my listview in a card. I have an sqflite database from which the settings are retrieved. This works well but there is one major problem: I have to hot reload my app for each new card to show in my listview.

What I would want, is for my listview page to be updated when I navigate back to it.

What I have tried is using Navigator Push to get back from my settings page to my listview page like this:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilesList(),
  );
```

This works in that my listview then updates immediately. But when I click the back button, instead of popping back to the homepage, I end up in the settings screen again, because this is where I pushed from. And so I can't go back to the main app screen.

Is there a solution? At the moment I have to choose between either my profiles list not updating but my navigation working, or my profiles list updating but my navigation not working.

In terms of navigation, what I would need is: Page 1 => Page 2 => Page 3 => Page 2 => Page 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem thanks to this: https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-navigation-cheatsheet-a-guide-to-the-navigator/

So basically, I had to pop from the settings page, but adding to it the value "true", like this:

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

Then, in my listview page, all I had to do was to wait for this value to come back, at which point I could reload my list, like this:

```
                 var navigationResult = await Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              ProfileCreator(),
                        ),
                      );
                      if (navigationResult == true){
                        setState(() {
                          getList();
                        });
```

I hope this is useful to someone some day...